# JavaFX - Animate along path parallel to tangent

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to get a car to animate along a curved path. The PathTransition.OrientationType only seems to give the option to keep the node perpendicular to the path instead of parallel.

Is there a way to make this parallel?

Here is a bit of what I have so far:

```
    VBox car = new VBox();

    Line track1 = new Line(242, 10, 242, 200);
    Line track2 = new Line(258, 10, 258, 200);
    Line track3 = new Line(242, 600, 242, 800);
    Line track4 = new Line(258, 600, 258, 800);

    CubicCurveTo curvePath1 = new CubicCurveTo();
    curvePath1.setControlX1(400.0f);
    curvePath1.setControlY1(300.0f);
    curvePath1.setControlX2(400.0f);
    curvePath1.setControlY2(500.0f);
    curvePath1.setX(250.0f);
    curvePath1.setY(600.0f);

    VBox station1 = new VBox();
    LoadingPosition stationUp = new LoadingPosition();
    LoadingPosition stationDown = new LoadingPosition();
    station1.getChildren().addAll(stationUp, stationDown);
    station1.setLayoutX(170);
    station1.setLayoutY(27);

    VBox station2 = new VBox();
    LoadingPosition station2Up = new LoadingPosition();
    LoadingPosition station2Down = new LoadingPosition();
    station2.getChildren().addAll(station2Up, station2Down);
    station2.setLayoutX(170);
    station2.setLayoutY(712);

    //Setting up the path
    Path path = new Path();
    path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(250f, 70f));
    path.getElements().add(new LineTo(250f, 200f));
    path.getElements().add(curvePath1);
    path.getElements().add(new LineTo(250f, 712f));
    //Instantiating PathTransition class
    PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();

    //Setting duration for the PathTransition
    pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(1000));

    //Setting Node on which the path transition will be applied
    pathTransition.setNode(car);

    //setting path for the path transition
    pathTransition.setPath(path);

    //setting up the cycle count
    pathTransition.setCycleCount(10);

    //setting auto reverse to be true
    pathTransition.setAutoReverse(true);

    pathTransition.setOrientation(PathTransition.OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);

    //Playing path transition
    pathTransition.play();
    //Applying parallel Translation to the circle
    ParallelTransition parallelTransition = new ParallelTransition(
            car, pathTransition);

    //Playing the animation
    parallelTransition.play();
    //Configuring group and scene
    Group root = new Group();
    root.getChildren().addAll(station1, station2, track1, track2, track3, track4, curveTrack1, curveTrack2, car, path);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1200, 900, Color.LIGHTGRAY);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Path Transition Example");
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

[Orthogonal to path instead of parallel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TK0pf.png)

Comment: See if you can find what you need [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/best_practices/jfxpub-best_practices.htm).

Comment: `ParallelTransition`s are used to run animations simultaneously. They do not change the orientation of an animated node. It seems like your car just needs to be rotated by 90° to be moved correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working by trying other ways to rotate the car, thanks to Fabian for suggesting. 
Sedrick's example also helped narrow down where to focus.

Here's what I added:

```
car.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(270,totalCarHeight/2,totalCarWidth));
```

The pivot points were a little unusual, but this made it perfectly centered on the path.
Previously, I tried:

```
car.setRotate(270);
```

Which did nothing, leading me to drift away from that idea.

Answer (score 0):

Altered code from [here](https://hajsoftutorial.com/javafx-tutorial/javafx-animation-pathtransition/)

imp

```
ort javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.animation.PathTransition.OrientationType;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.CubicCurveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class JavaFXApplication extends Application
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {

        primaryStage.setTitle("PathTransition");

        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 300, Color.GREY);

        //ImageView car = new ImageView(new Image("http://hajsoftutorial.com/im/smallcar.png"));
        Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("car.png"));
        ImageView car = new ImageView(image);
        car.setFitHeight(40);
        car.setPreserveRatio(true);

        Path road = new Path();
        road.setStrokeWidth(30);

        MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo();
        moveTo.setX(150);
        moveTo.setY(30);

        LineTo line1 = new LineTo();
        line1.setX(650);
        line1.setY(30);

        CubicCurveTo cubicTo = new CubicCurveTo();
        cubicTo.setControlX1(800);
        cubicTo.setControlY1(30);
        cubicTo.setControlX2(800);
        cubicTo.setControlY2(270);
        cubicTo.setX(650);
        cubicTo.setY(270);

        LineTo line2 = new LineTo();
        line2.setX(150);
        line2.setY(270);

        CubicCurveTo cubicTo2 = new CubicCurveTo();
        cubicTo2.setControlX1(0);
        cubicTo2.setControlY1(270);
        cubicTo2.setControlX2(0);
        cubicTo2.setControlY2(30);
        cubicTo2.setX(150);
        cubicTo2.setY(30);

        road.getElements().addAll(moveTo, line1, cubicTo, line2, cubicTo2);

        PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();
        pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(10000));
        pathTransition.setNode(car);
        pathTransition.setPath(road);
        pathTransition.setOrientation(OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);
        pathTransition.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        pathTransition.play();

        root.getChildren().addAll(road, car);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```